# Video uploading with the graph API using cURL and PHP

Tags: video, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to upload a video using the graph API. (I don't use the legacy REST API since Facebook does not encourage to do so).

Basically I'm following the basic video upload example in *[Yunnan Wu
Platform Updates: Operation Developer Love](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/)*, where it uses a HTML form to upload the file.
Instead I want to do it automatically without user interaction and tried with [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL). My code segment looks like following (which I found in some other post here)

```
$post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos?"
 . "title=" . $video_title. "&description=" . $video_desc 
 . "&". $access_token;

$ch = curl_init();
$data[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath("klfaceevo.mp4");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
```

I receive the following.

> Method Not Implemented
>
> Invalid method in request

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Facebook PHP SDK, it will do most of the job for you. This is how I do automatic video publishing to a page.

- **Get access token with the right permissions**

  This step is only done the first time to get a valid access token. If you specify the offline_access permission, as in the example, this token will not expire (unless the user changes password I think). Facebook documentation calls it "long-lived". So store the token and your application is allowed to publish videos (and other stuff) without the interaction of the user at any time.

  > ```
  >   // Set up params
  >   $params = array('canvas' => 1,
  >                  'fbconnect' => 0,
  >                  'scope' => "video_upload,publish_stream,manage_pages,offline_access");
  >
  >   // Get login URL
  >   $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
  >
  >   // Redirect user to the login URL
  >   header("Location:{$loginUrl}");
  > ```
- **Create a new instance of the Facebook object and call it's api() method**

  ```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => $app_id,
                                    'secret' => $app_secret,
                                    'cookie' => TRUE,
                                    ));


    try {
          $video = $facebook->api('/<page id>/videos', 'POST', 
                              array('access_token' => $access_token,
                                    'source' => '@' . $file,
                                    'description' => $video_desc,
                                    ));

            }catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
               error_log($e);
         }
  ```
- **Some notes**

  - Videos must not be bigger than 1 GB.
  - The CURLOPT_TIMEOUT is set to 60 (seconds) as default. Increase this value if you get a timeout. You find this setting in base_facebook.php.
  - If you want to handle special chars be sure to use utf-8 encoding and htmlspecialchars(). (If you hardcode text don't forget to set your editor to utf-8 encoding like I did).
  - It can take several minutes before your video is displayed on Facebook.

Comment: Hi, how do i connect to facebook if im on a business page? I don't have an app, I cant get the api key and secret key. I need to get all videos that i have uploaded on facebook. I know it can be done through FQL query. I have the Facebook PHP SDK. Is there any other way that I can get all my videos without using the api key and secret key? Or, is there a way I can get the api key and secret key?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put all of the parameters within the $data array, and then trim off the query string parameters.

i.e.

```
$video_title = "test title";
$video_desc = "test desc";
$access_token = YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN;

$data = array('name' => 'file', 'file' => '@'.realpath("movie.m4v"), 'access_token' => $access_token, '_title' => $video_title, 'description' => $video_desc);
$post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos";
```